# XQuery Nested Query

Tags: sum, xquery, sequence, aggregates

I can't figure out how to execute this query:

**Using XQuery,
For each rep number, output:**

A. **firstname**, **lastname** of the rep.

B. **customer name** for each customer associated with the rep.

C.**total amount of money** (excluding tax) billed **for all customers** associated with the rep.

**Premiere Database schema:**

-A **Customer** structure has attributes CustomerNumber, RepNum (assigned rep), etc.

-A **Rep** structure has attributes RepNum, etc.

-An **Orders** structure has attributes CustomerNumber, OrderNum, etc.

-An **OrderLine** structure has attributes OrderNum, NumOrdered, QuotedPrice(per -item), etc.

*Multiple order lines can have the same order number.

**Sample desired output:**

**Q4 Output:**

```
<results>
  <rep repnum="20" firstname="Valerie" lastname="Kaiser">
    <customer name="Al's Appliance and Sport"/>
    <customer name="Kline's"/>
    <customer name="All Season"/>
    <Revenue total="$736.45"/>
  </rep>
  <rep repnum="35" firstname="Richard" lastname="Hull">
    <customer name="Brookings Direct"/>
    <customer name="The Everything Shop"/>
    <customer name="Lee's Sport and Appliance"/>
    <customer name="Deerfield's Four Seasons"/>
    <Revenue total="$2,509.80"/>
  </rep>
  <rep repnum="65" firstname="Juan" lastname="Perez">
    <customer name="Ferguson's"/>
    <customer name="Bargains Galore"/>
    <customer name="Johnson's Department Store"/>
    <Revenue total="$5,664.89"/>
  </rep>
</results>
```

**The output I'm getting:**

```
<results>
  <rep>
    <rep repnum="20" firstname="Valerie" lastname="Kaiser"/>
    <customer name="Al's Appliance and Sport"/>
    <customer name="Kline's"/>
    <customer name="All Season"/>
    <Revenue total="0"/>
  </rep>
  <rep>
    <rep repnum="35" firstname="Richard" lastname="Hull"/>
    <customer name="Brookings Direct"/>
    <customer name="The Everything Shop"/>
    <customer name="Lee's Sport and Appliance"/>
    <customer name="Deerfield's Four Seasons"/>
    <Revenue total="0"/>
  </rep>
  <rep>
    <rep repnum="65" firstname="Juan" lastname="Perez"/>
    <customer name="Ferguson's"/>
    <customer name="Bargains Galore"/>
    <customer name="Johnson's Department Store"/>
    <Revenue total="0"/>
  </rep>
</results>
```

Revenue per rep is 0!

**My code:**

```
<results>
  {
    for $r in doc("../premiere/Rep.xml")//Rep
    let $c := doc("../premiere/Customer.xml")//Customer[RepNum = $r/RepNum]

    return 
      <rep>
        <rep repnum = "{$r/RepNum}" firstname="{$r/FirstName}" lastname="{$r/LastName}"/>

        {for $customer in $c 
        return
           <customer name= "{ $customer/CustomerName}"/>}

        <Revenue total=  "{sum(
             for $customer in $c 
             let $o := doc("../premiere/Orders.xml")//Orders[CustomerNumber = $customer/CustomerNumber]
             let $customerAmount := sum(
                 for $order in $o
                 let $l := doc("../premiere/OrderLine.xml")//OrderLine[OrderNum = $order/OrderNum]
                 let $orderAmount := format-number(sum(
                     for $lineItem in $l
                     let $LineAmount := (data($lineItem/NumOrdered) * data($lineItem/QuotedPrice))
                     return 
                       $LineAmount
                 ), '$,000.00')
                 return
                   $orderAmount
             )
             return
               $customerAmount
         )}"
         />
      </rep>

  }
</results>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In `$orderAmount` you are formatting the sum, which returns a string. Then in `$customerAmount` you are summing this string. I would expect that to operation raise an error (sum requires values that can be cast as xs:double and that are of a type that supports addition, requirements that the xs:string data type does not meet), so why you're getting `0` as the result of this operation rather than an error is strange to me. See the function signature for `fn:sum()`. https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-sum

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was really helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, as @joewiz pointed out, you format the partial sums into strings before you sum them up, which should definitely raise an error if executed. Since it does not, I would suspect that the outer sum never adds up any values.

You did not provide any example data, but I found [this SQL file](http://163.238.35.144/~chi/MySQL/Premier%20database/MySQL-Premiere.txt) for a *Premiere* data set that seems to match yours. One important difference is that `CUSTOMER` has an attribute `CUSTOMER_NUM`, not `CUSTOMER_NUMBER` like in your description. If the element is also called `CustomerNum` instead of `CustomerNumber` in your data set, then `let $o := doc("../premiere/Orders.xml")//Orders[CustomerNumber = $customer/CustomerNumber]` will silently be evaluated to the empty sequence and the sum is `0`.

Here is a version of your query that works for me and produces the exact output you wanted when evaluated on the values from the SQL file:

```
<results>{
  for $r in doc("../premiere/Rep.xml")//Rep
  let $c := doc("../premiere/Customer.xml")//Customer[RepNum = $r/RepNum]
  return <rep>{
      <rep repnum = "{$r/RepNum}" firstname="{$r/FirstName}" lastname="{$r/LastName}"/>,

      for $customer in $c 
      return <customer name="{$customer/CustomerName}"/>,

      let $total :=
        sum(
          for $customer in $c
          for $order in doc("../premiere/Orders.xml")//Orders[CustomerNum = $customer/CustomerNumber]
          for $lineItem in doc("../premiere/OrderLine.xml")//OrderLine[OrderNum = $order/OrderNum]
          return $lineItem/NumOrdered * $lineItem/QuotedPrice
        )
      return <Revenue total="{format-number($total, '$,000.00')}"/>
  }</rep>
}</results>
```

I have simplified it by merging the two sums into one and inlining a few variables, and I moved the number formatting out to the correct spot.

Comment: Effectively, the customer attribute name was incorrect, it was meant to be CustomerNum. Huge oversight on my part considering at that point I had already done some queries on that specific attribute. The formatting inside the partial sum was incorrect as well, thanks for pointing out both mistakes. I really appreciate the simplified code, it brought to my attention how redundant the nested 'let' statements and partial sums were. Great Answer!